# grails DefaultGrailsDomainClass.getIdentifier always returns 'id as identifier

Tags: grails, groovy, grails3

I'm trying to write a generator for an angular-based CRUD application (scaffolding, but client-side, using angular)

Part of it consists on extracting the meta-information from GORM
Now, I've hit a hard wall, apparently.

I want to handle the case where the ID field is not generated, but managed by the application.
Say I have a class definition like:

```
@Resource(readOnly = false, formats = ['json', 'xml'])
class Phone {

    int age
    String phoneId
    String imageUrl
    String name
    String snippet

    static mapping = {
        id name: 'phoneId', generator: 'assigned'
}

    static constraints = {
        snippet(nullable: true, maxSize: 2000)
    }
}
```

I would like to retrieve the field serving as identifier for this class, which here should be 'phoneId'.

But if I ask for:

```
grailsApplication.getDomainClass(com.phonecat.Phone.getName()).identifier
```

What I get instead is a Property, called 'id' of type Long:

```
DefaultGrailsDomainClassProperty@6e59cb9b name = 'id', type = Long, persistent = true, optional = false, association = false, bidirectional = false, association-type = [null]]
```

Am I mis-using the getIdentifier method?
Is there something I missed?
Or have I hit a bug in Grails/GORM?

For completeness, here is the version of GORM I'm using (as far as I can tell... so many things changed recently on gorm side...):

from build.groovy:

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5"
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.2.Final"
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:5.1.2.Final"
```

Also, I'm using grails console plugin to run these tests:

```
runtime 'org.grails.plugins:grails-console:2.0.6'
```

(which I find really great)
But probably the same could be run from within the normal command-line console.

Here is the code I used:

```
import com.phonecat.*

println grailsApplication.getDomainClass(Phone.getName()).identifier

def d = grailsApplication.getDomainClass(Phone.getName())
println "${d.class} ${d.clazz.name} ${d.identifier}"

def pd = Phone.findAll().each {c ->
    println "${c.id} ${c.phoneId}"
}
null
```

The question is: supposing (as it actually happens to be ...) that I'm writing a plugin to retrieve the meta-information about a domain class; How can I obtain from GORM the information that this class has been assigned the field 'phoneId' as unique identifier, and this is the value I should look at when querying the  resource through REST?

Comment: Did you try to change `String phoneId` to `String id`? Moreover remember to remove `phoneId` from constraints.

Comment: @Michael_Szulc: phoneId() within constraints was there only to ensure the order in which the fields are rendered when using scaffolding. Removed as they are, indeed, useless for this question.
I tried what you suggest, and in this case the identifier method reports correctly an id of name 'id' and type String.
BUT that won't solve my issue: I'm trying to modify my model. I'm actually writing a plugin that will retrieve the meta-information of my model (so, the identifier field also). So I want a method to retrieve the name of the field anyone has given as unique identifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you should favour the GORM API instead of the GrailsDomainClass if you want to inspect the mapping of you model. To do that you need to get a reference to the [MappingContext](http://gorm.grails.org/latest/api/org/grails/datastore/mapping/model/MappingContext.html) (it can be dependency injected by Spring). Then:

```
 PersistentEntity entity = mappingContext.getPersistentEntity(Phone.name)
 println entity.identity.name
```

Comment: Whoops! Didn't notice god himself answered my question...
Thanks Graeme for pointing out this. didn't know about MappingContext.

And, yes, That definitely works. I correctly get back an id with name 'phoneId' and type String.
Now... that will mean I will have to refactor all my code. But for sure it will become much cleaner.